# Parameter and empty string issues

Tags: powershell, exchange, exchange-2010

Created the below script to create multiple room mailboxes from a CSV, but have the following errors:

- A parameter cannot be found the matches parameter name 'Encoding'.
- Cannot bind arguement to parameter 'Name' because it is an empty string.
- Cannot bing argue to parameter 'Identity' because it is null.

```
$roomlist = Import-csv C:\temp\rooms.csv -Encoding ASCII
$orgunit = "OU=************"
foreach($room in $roomlist){
$roomname = $room.Fullname
#write-host $roomname
$first = $room.Site
$last = $room.Room
$capacity = $room.cap
$mailalias = $room.Fullname -replace '\W',''
$mail = $mailalias + "@***email address***"
$samaccountname = $room.samaccountname
$upnname = $samaccountname + "@***email address***"
#write-host $roomname $mail $capacity $mailalias $samchop
write-host $samaccountname 
New-Mailbox -Name $roomname -Room -SamAccountName $samaccountname -FirstName $first -LastName $last -UserPrincipalName $upnname -PrimarySmtpAddress $mail -alias $mailalias -ResourceCapacity $capacity -Database 'DBNAME' -OrganizationalUnit $orgunit
#set-CalendarProcessing $roomname -AutomateProcessing autoaccept
Set-Mailbox -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled $true -Identity $roomname
}
```

Comment: please add the FULL text of the 1st error to your Question. that should pave some useful info about the _cause_ of the error. [*grin*] ///// also, using proper indents makes your code easier to read/understand/debug. your current formatting makes your code needlessly difficult to parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the version of your PowerShell? Run the command **`Get-Host`**  to view that(**`Version`**):

[image]

1. For the first error `A parameter cannot be found the matches parameter name 'Encoding'.`, "**The parameter -Encoding was introduced in PowerShell 3.0**": **[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45583933/powershell-import-csv-with-encoding-does-not-work-in-sql-server)**, therefore, you couldn't use this parameter if your PowerShell version is lower than 3.0, you need remove it in your script or upgrade PowerShell version.
2. For the 2rd and 3rd errors, it seems that they are related with the format of the .csv file. Please check if the format of your .csv file is correct, the .csv file which is converted to .txt should be like the following(`"Object1", "Object2"`):

[image]

- My test result(with a correct format) without the `-Encoding` parameter is for your
  reference:

[image]

**Edit:** However, there are two properties(**First Name** and **Last Name**) unable to be looked up via the **`Get-Mailbox`** cmdlet, you need run the following commands to find them:

```
$roomlist = Import-csv C:\temp\rooms.csv
foreach($room in $roomlist){Get-ADUser -Identity $room.Fullname -Properties * | Select Name, GivenName, SN}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Turned out the notepad didn't have the samaccountnem header!